# Making multi-histogram in ggplot, not recognizing grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a stack of histograms (or a ridgeplot) so I can compare distributions at certain timepoints in my observations.

[I used this source for the histogram](https://r-graphics.org/recipe-distribution-multi-hist),  [and this for the ridge plots](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html).
However, I cannot figure out how to set up my code to make either a stacked histogram of each length (L) by week, so that I can see L distributions at different weeks. I have tried the fill option in ggplot (which in the example seems to produce automatic color differences for the weeks because it is in the aes()?) and other "stacks" using the y= argument, but haven't had much success, I think due to the way my data is set up. If anyone can help me figure out how to make multiple histograms by week, that would be useful!

Thanks!

```
#fake data
L = rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
t = c((rep.int(7,10)), (rep.int(14,20)), rep.int(21,30), rep.int(28,20), (rep.int(31, 20)), (rep.int(36,10)))
fake = data.frame(cbind(L,t))

#subset data into weeks for convenience
dayofweek = seq(7,120,7)
fake2 = as.data.frame(subset(fake, t %in% dayofweek))
fake2$week <- floor(fake2$t/7)

#Plots, basic code
ggplot(fake2, aes(x=L, fill=week)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image: example ggplot output]

Comment: What is the `sn_sz_week` variable?

Comment: Please make sure your example is reproducible by defining all variables. And when you say it "isn't working" can you be more specific about what you expected the output to look like?

Comment: Ah sorry, I hadn't switched over my real data variable hidden in the one line. It now reads the fake data set defined. I will also post an example of what I see vs what I need

Answer (score 0):

I tried facet_grid before, but for some reason facet_wrap actually at least separated the graphs correctly, AND magically made the color fill work:

```
ggplot(fake2, aes(x=L, fill = week)) +
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_wrap(.~week)
```

[image]